# User rating - sql schema optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, relational-database, query-optimization

I have a small sketch of user's rank schema of data:

```
CREATE TABLE user 
    (
     user_id int auto_increment primary key, 
     nickname varchar(50), 
     details varchar(30)
    );

CREATE TABLE rank 
    (
     rank_id int auto_increment primary key, 
     level int,
     type varchar(20) 
    );

CREATE TABLE user_rank
    (
      user_id int auto_increment not null,
      rank_id int auto_increment not null,
      FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id),
      FOREIGN KEY (rank_id) REFERENCES rank(rank_id),
    );


INSERT INTO user
(nickname, details)
VALUES
('Horax', 'admin@sqlfiddle.com'),
('Goan', '@sqlfiddle');

INSERT INTO rank
(level, type)
VALUES
(10, 'bronze'),
(15, 'gold');

INSERT INTO user_rank
(user_id, rank_id)
VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 2),
(3, 3),
(4, 4);
```

And I want to select (a) N users with top rating and (b) get the user nickname and user details by user_id at ANY time QUICKLY with amount of data, let's say, 1 million records:

```
SELECT * FROM user_rank LEFT JOIN user ON user_rank.user_id = user.user_id
LEFT JOIN rank ON rank.rank_id = user_rank.rank_id 
ORDER by level DESC
LIMIT N
```

and

```
SELECT user.nickname, user.details FROM user_rank LEFT JOIN user ON user_rank.user_id = user.user_id
LEFT JOIN rank ON rank.rank_id = user_rank.rank_id 
WHERE user.user_id = 10
```

How to tune this schema and queries for ratings up in a way of performance? What weak spots do you see?

Thank you forehand for your help, colleagues!

Comment: why are you joining to anything in second query if all you are selecting are fields from user based on user_id?

Answer (score 0):

How many rows will you eventually have?

This is a classic Many-to-many relation table, correct?  It won't work, and is grossly inefficient, as is.  Change it to this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_rank (
    user_id int not null,
    rank_id int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, rank_id),
    INDEX(rank_id, user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

(Add the FOREIGN KEYs back in, if you like.)

In `rank` you have both `rank_id` and `level`.  If the `level` is unique in the table, make it the PRIMARY KEY and get rid of `rank_id` (and change other references to `rank_id`).

Those changes should serve you well into the millions of rows.

If a user does not have many levels, then get rid of the table!  Simply put the `level` into the `user` table (and get rid of `rank_id`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The only question I have is how to optimize the queries to this scheme? Are the queries that I mentioned in the main text of the message optimal for this scheme or not?

Comment: (I added to 'answer')

Comment: I didn't notice any change, sorry.

Comment: If a user does not have many levels, then get rid of the table! Simply put the level into the user table (and get rid of rank_id).